# Why -bash: /usr/bin/g++: cannot execute binary file?

Tags: macos, unix, gcc, g++, alias

```
simpatico$ /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5664~89/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

simpatico$ /usr/bin/g++ -v
-bash: /usr/bin/g++: cannot execute binary file
```

I don't know of a command that proves that /usr/bin/g++  is an alias of /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2.

Comment: You want to know where /usr/bin/g++ is?

Comment: I know where it's it's an alias to /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2. I don't know of a command that would prove it to you. My goal is to not get -bash: /usr/bin/g++: cannot execute binary file?

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: `/usr/bin/g++` will be a link to `/usr/bin/g++-4.2` (or something like that), and is a copy of the `g++` in `/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2`, but it sounds like your install has issues or your `g++-4.2` is not executable in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: /usr/bin/g++ -v works on my system. (10.6.5) I would check your XCode install.

Comment: ls -l /usr/bin/g++
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 simpatico  wheel  103368 13 Dez 22:56 /usr/bin/g++
Doesn't tell where the alias points to (but through Finder I tell it's indeed pointing to /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2.

There is nothing wrong with my xcode installation I think, because as reported above /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -v works.

Comment: Is your `/usr/bin/g++` in a format that's suitable for your architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simpatico$  sudo gcc_select  gcc42

Comment: but: simpatico$ /usr/bin/g++ -v
-bash: /usr/bin/g++: cannot execute binary file